# indeterminate css style for a checkbox styled with label

Tags: javascript, css

I am using this style to change the appearence of a checkbox:

```
th .checkbox label::before,th .checkbox label::before {
      content: "";
      display: inline-block;
      position: absolute;
      width: 17px;
      height: 17px;
      left: -20px;
      border: 1px solid #cccccc;
      border-radius: 3px;
      background-color: #fff;
      -webkit-transition: border 0.15s ease-in-out, color 0.15s ease-in-out;
      -o-transition: border 0.15s ease-in-out, color 0.15s ease-in-out;
      transition: border 0.15s ease-in-out, color 0.15s ease-in-out;
    }
th .checkbox label::after {
      display: inline-block;
      position: absolute;
      width: 16px;
      height: 16px;
      left: -21px;
      top: 0;
      padding-left: 3px;
      padding-top: 1px;
      font-size: 11px;
      color: #555555;
    }
```

this works perfectly for **before** and **after** but the interdeterminate style in chrome do not have the correct position. So i tried it with:

```
th .checkbox label::indeterminate {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  left: -20px;
  top: 0;
  padding-left: 3px;
  padding-top: 1px;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #555555;
}
```

but it does not work :(. how could I fix this and give the indeterminate at least a `left: -21px;` style.

thank you in advance!

Comment: Please add your HTML so we can understand what is going on.

Comment: <th class="dt-checkboxes-cell dt-checkboxes-select-all sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 20px;" data-col="0" aria-label=" All"><div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" class="dt-checkboxes"><label></label></div></th>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`indeterminate` is a **pseudo class** so it starts with `:` while `before` and `after` are **pseudo elements** and start with `::`

```
th .checkbox label:indeterminate {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  left: -20px;
  top: 0;
  padding-left: 3px;
  padding-top: 1px;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #555555;
}
```

Please refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:indeterminate

and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before

Comment: thank you for your hint! but it is still not working :( ... i recognized that ::after and ::before appear in the html source code but :indeterminate does not...